# What is the purpose of using TThread.Synchronize inside a AnonymousThread?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, firemonkey

I came across this piece of `Delphi` code while searching for background methods to execute tasks in firemonkey.

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
            procedure()
            begin
                Sleep(10000);
                TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
                procedure
                begin
                    Button2.Text := 'OK';
                end);
            end).Start;
```

Is TThread.Synchronize at this case really necessary?

Comment: It's accessing UI controls (the button), and therefore needs to be synchronized with the main thread. All access to UI controls need to occur in the main thread.

Comment: Then, it wouldn't be necessary to include it if we're dealing with background tasks?

Comment: If those background tasks don't do anything with the UI or any other thread, then that's correct. However, this particular thread seems very pointless with the snippet of code you provide. It's like using an airplane to go around the block.

Comment: It has nothing special to do with AnonymousThread. It is a very easy rule: *Every time when `TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadId <> MainThreadId` evaluates `true` you **must** use `TThread.Synchronize` to access UI-Controls*. Thats all

Comment: If that *background task* touches UI controls, it's necessary. If it doesn't, it's not. I thought I said that already. :-) It doesn't matter if the thread is anonymous or it's name is Fred, the rule is the same. UI access **must be done in the main thread**.

Comment: Actually I would use `TThread.Queue` instead.

Comment: @Holmes: It depends on the nature of the synced operation. If the operation does not need to pass a result from the main thread back to the thread, `TThread.Queue()` is better to use, as it does not block the thread. You just have to be careful with any pointers you access in the operation, in case the thread frees them before the operation is performed. On the other hand, if the operation needs to pass a result from the main thread back to the thread, use `TThread.Synchronize()` instead, as it blocks the thread until the operation is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TButton.Text changes a property of a Window object, which is inherently non-thread-safe, and is only to be accessed directly from the thread which created it OR via message sends/posts.

What TThread.Synchronize does is - it wraps the procedure together with a waitable object, places this to a queue, and waits on the handle - it may post a message to the main thread to wake it up.

If the code behind TButton.Text was implemented via posted message - and is is not - it would be safe to call from other threads, but it would not take effect immediately.

Long story short - you definitely have to call this via Synchronize, for good reasons.

Comment: Do note that FireMonkey is being used in the example, and FireMonkey does not use Window objects for any UI controls other than top-level Forms (since they interest with the OS directly). Child controls are custom drawn and do not rely on Windows. But, you are correct that UI property changes are still inherently thread-unsafe and need to be synced in general.